# Wordpress installation issue for my website

Tags: php, wordpress, heidisql

I just downloaded the Wordpress files to my website and then uploaded them to my server as instructed. I created a HeidiSQL database and have made sure that all of the necessary info [dbase name, username, password, secret keys, etc.] was entered into the wp-config file. Then, when I'm all ready to install Wordpress, I go to www.mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/install.php, and here's the error message I got:

```
Warning: require(/home1/reanima1/public_html/sites/mysite.com/blog/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/reanima1/public_html/sites/mysite.com/blog/wp-settings.php on line 21

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home1/reanima1/public_html/sites/mysite.com/blog/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home1/reanima1/public_html/sites/mysite.com/blog/wp-settings.php on line 21
```

I'm surmising that something wasn't copacetic in some of the Wordpress files that I downloaded, but I don't know where to start. Or I could be missing something basic. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there are proper read and write privileges?

Comment: Did you check that this file blog/wp-includes/load.php actually exist? If not, you might want to re-upload all the WP files. Also check that the permissions are right on the files.

Answer (score 1):

With errors such as that - missing files - the first two troubleshooting steps are

1) download a fresh archive from WordPress and then reupload all core WordPress files and folders, and

2) check file/folder permissions by reading [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)